# Accessing file properties like owner, comment, subject

Tags: files-and-directories

The Wolfram Language has various functions for getting file properties, for example: `FileHash[]`, `FileByteCount[]`, and various `FileDate[]` types.  How about other attributes, like (in particular) "Comments"?

Comment: my guess they have stayed away from providing intrinsics for things that are highly OS dependent.

Comment: @george2079 that sound plausible. I thought that someone might have a special gizmo for this.

Comment: if you're on OSX you can use `RunThrough` with the command line util `xattr`, much like in the deleted answer below (say `man xattr` in a terminal to find out what it does).

Comment: @acl I'm on Windows 10, but there is probably  something similar to xattr for windows.